# Can non-humans master a wand in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory, magical-items, wandlore

Inspired by [Would Nagini have become the master of the Elder Wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54679/would-nagini-have-become-the-master-of-the-elder-wand)

Somehow it seems odd to me that wand ownership may pass to just any animal (even magical ones, such as Nagini), but Harry Potter has lots of sentient non-humans as well.
Would it be possible for such humanoids (goblins, centaurs, merpeople, giants, etc, or any living creature in general) to be able to master (or at least use) a wand?

Some references:

In the last book Griphook states that the right to carry wands has been long contested between wizards and goblins, indicating goblins probably *can* use wands, but the wizards won't let them.

In the Goblet of Fire after the Quidditch World Cup, some wizards accuse Winky of casting Voldemort's mark using a wand (I will try to find the quotes later), indicating it might be possible for house elves to use wands

I think there are a few other such incidents as well; I will probably add them as I remember.

PS: I found this: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand_Ban
but it does not cite any references. Could anyone please approve or disapprove this with the relevant quotes?

Comment: I have nought but speculation derived from the books but upon my reading, the fact that goblins *want* to carry wands told me that they could use them: why else would they want them? I've tried looking for examples of goblins breaking the wand-ban and using a wand illegally but came up dry.

Comment: FYI: I edited out the goblins part from my answer which inspired this; since the quote provided in the comments indicates that they CAN (but aren't allowed to).

Comment: @Mac:  Like Griphook said, he believes wizards are withholding secrets of wand use from goblins. Maybe they just believe they can use a wand, or perhaps they can channel their magic through a wand but are not physically able to do so as good as the wizards, but have somehow developed a concept among themselves that wizards are deliberately not allowing them to practice with wands and that's why they are not that good in using them

Comment: @user13267 - should be an answer :)

Comment: @DVK: may be, but this is all speculation on my part. I don't have any sources.

Comment: @user13267 - you did in the comments to my answer.

Comment: @DVK: but still, it doesn't seem to be enough to approve or disapprove of anything. The text is still vague on this.

Comment: I like what @user13267 said in reply to my comment, if I may restate -- perhaps any magical creature (sentient) can use a wand but only so as to channel their own magic, rather than wizard's spells. So a goblin could use a wand to channel GOBLIN magic but not the magic wizards and witches use. Speculation though. This appears to be one of those voids in Harry Potter lore that is perhaps hinted at (I mean, goblins WANT to use wands as I said but then as User13267 said, that proves nothing) but never answered: I've just browsed Rowling's FAQs and interviews and found nothing about this.

Comment: How could an animal have **grabbed the wand against the will of its master**, In case of your question, the wand would remain undefeated and its allegiance would pass to no one,however its master shall be defeated(Like dumbledore planned with the elder wand)

Comment: Just because it's allegiance wouldn't be with the other person doesn't mean that the wand will not work... Remember Voldemort tried using the wand and it wasn't actually working as well as it should because he wasn't the proper owner of it.  Also the monster races of Harry Potter are more than just mere animals.

Comment: @DoctorWho22, may be they could it, but **they can't master it** and thats what the question is all about..Can non humans **master** a wand in HP

Comment: Yes but you only stated how can an animal grab the the wand against the will of it's master.  That's something completely different.

Comment: As far as I remember the allegiance changes by either grabbing the wand or simply defeating the wand

Comment: I believe that only counts for the Elder Wand.  It was even stated by Rowling, "most wands have some allegiance to their own masters, the Elder Wand only responds to power." in the wikipedia for magical objects in harry potter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Canon suggests that goblins could certainly use wands, and probably other non-human creatures as well.

The *Goblet of Fire* quote you want is this one, which introduces the wand ban:

> “Here, look.” Mr. Diggory held up a wand and showed it to Mr. Weasley. “Had it in her [Winky’s] hand. So that’s clause three of the Code of Wand Use broken, for a start. **No non-human creature is permitted to carry or use a wand.**”

This suggests that there are non-human creatures can use wands (although mastery is still up for debate). If they couldn’t use them, then the law would be redundant.

The wording of the law marks humans out as different from other creatures, and reads like a deliberate attempt to promote human supremacy. Various quotes from JKR suggest that you need a wand to do certain forms of advanced magic. Restricting access to wands would prevent them from using this magic.

In a [2001 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-comicrelief-staff.htm), she suggests that wands are necessary for “really good spells”:

> Do you need a wand to do magic?
>
> You can do unfocused and uncontrolled magic without a wand (for instance when Harry blows up Aunt Marge) but **to do really good spells, yes, you need a wand.**

In a [2006 interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0801-radiocityreading1partial.html), she similarly says that wands are necessary to make potions:

> There is a magical component to the potion, not just the ingredients. So, at some point you’re going to have to use a wand.

House-elves and goblins both have branches of advanced magic that don't require wands (apparition and metalwork, for example). However, neither show an aptitude in spells or potion-making; this does suggest that a wand ban was a deliberate attempt to prevent non-human creatures accessing certain branches of magic.

#### Case study: goblins

We have enough detail in the canon to study goblins in particular.

In *Deathly Hallows*, Griphook explicitly states that wizards are using a wand ban to restrict the magical abilities of goblins:

> “The right to carry a wand,” said the goblin quietly, “has long been contested between wizards and goblins.”
>
> “Well, goblins can do magic without wands,” said Ron.
>
> “That is immaterial! **Wizards refuse to share the secrets of wandlore with other magical beings, they deny us the possibility of extending our powers!**”
>
> […]
>
> “As the Dark Lord becomes ever more powerful, your race is set still more firmly above mine!”

This tension is hinted more subtley in *Order of the Phoenix*:

> “It depends what they're [goblins are] offered,” said Lupin. “And I’m not talking about gold; if they’re offered freedoms we’ve been denying them for centuries they’re going to be tempted.”

Presumably these freedoms include the ability to carry a wand.

The “centuries” comment comes from the [third WOMBAT (written by JKR)](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizworld/wombat/wombat3comments.html), which states that the wand ban was passed in 1631:

> The Ministry of Magic Decree of 1631, preventing all magical beings other than wizards carrying a wand.

There are various references to a goblin rebellion in 1612, based in Hogsmeade. There's no canon evidence that the wand ban was directly prompted by this rebellion, but it probably helped.

Finally, in the late 1990s, JKR wrote and released four copies of the *Daily Prophet*, called *The Daily Prophet newsletters*, to the UK fan club. I can't find full text copies online (see [this discussion](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Daily_Prophet_Newsletters) on HP Wikia), but the [HPL Lexicon has a good summary](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/about/sources/source_dp.html), which includes this piece on goblins:

> **Goblin riots erupt in Chipping Clodbury**
>
> B.O.G. (Brotherhood of Goblins) supporters ran riot during a meeting with representatives from the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures. The goblins used illegal wands for transfiguration and called for the release of activist Hodrod the Horny-Handed. Goblin-wizard relations are reported to be at an all time low.

Here we see the goblins actually using wands, and wizards getting angsty about it.

Given how keen goblins are to be allowed to use and study wands, it only seems logical that they would be able to use them. There’s nothing to indicate goblins are unusual in this respect, so we may assume that other non-human creatures can use wands as well.

Comment: What about Fleur?  Does her use of a wand suggest that veela can use them, or does she have too much human in her?

Answer (score 6):

I think that any creature that can knowingly use magic, could use wands. While Hagrid is half human, he is also half giant and had no problems using a wand (prior to being kicked out of Hogwarts, anyway).

The quote that you reference is here:

> Griphook: "The right to carry a wand has long been contested between wizards and goblins."
>
> Ron Weasley: "Well, goblins can do magic without wands."
>
> Griphook: "That is immaterial! Wizards refuse to share the secrets of wandlore with other magical beings, they deny us the possibility of extending our powers!"

I don't think that it solely the use of wands, but also the secrets of crafting the wands. Having the wands wouldn't necessarily give them any more power, but allow them to focus and extend their innate abilities, which presumably could be done by any sentient magical being. Griphook doesn't just reference goblins, he references all magical beings. This is somewhat reinforced by the aphorism "The wand chooses the wizard".

There is also some evidence that wands are, to an extent, self aware/activating, perhaps as an extension of having a piece of a magical creature at its core.

Comment: I like how you are hinting that wands are made exclusively to unleash humans' powers. It gives a lot of sense to Griphook's quote.

Answer (score 5):

## Possibly - a goblin uses a wand in the “Fantastic Beasts” movie.

There’s at least one case seen of non-human wand use. In the screenplay for “Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them”, there’s a goblin jazz singer who’s mentioned as having a wand and using it to create smoke effects during her performance.

> *“A glamorous goblin* JAZZ SINGER *croons on a stage full of goblin musicians, smoky images wafting from her wand to illustrate her lyrics. All is dingy and shabby, an atmosphere of menacing fun.”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

It’s not said if she’s *mastered* it, but this is an example of a non-human shown using a wand.