# Wouldn't the Elder Wand belong to Neville, not Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

In the Harry Potter series, wouldn't the Elder Wand belong to Neville, not Harry? Since it belonged to Dumbledore, then Snape killed him, then Nagini killed Snape, then Neville killed Nagini, wouldn't it belong to him instead?

Comment: This is a pretty major plot point from the books...

Comment: Your logic is not based on canon.

The wand went to Malfoy not Snape because Draco disarmed Dumbledore. Harry then disarmed Draco.

Comment: Sorry, I was just wondering. But, my logic is right. It did say in the book that someone gets the Elder Wand by killing the original owner.

Comment: They "get" the Elder Wand by defeating the original owner. When Malfoy disarmed Dumbledore, Dumbledore was defeated. It just so happens that the Elder Wand *usually* is involved in battles that involve death due to it's reputation.

Comment: Sorry for closing this question after answering it. After some discussion in chat, I've now reopened it; others can close it again if they see fit.

Comment: Some of the characters in the book do indeed say that to get the Elder Wand you have to kill the original owner.  However, we later discover that they were mistaken.

Comment: Your logic includes Nagini as being capable of using a wand... that's absurd.

Comment: @T.J.L. UPDATE: [Would Nagini have become the master of the Elder Wand? (updated with fantastic beasts)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247069/would-nagini-have-become-the-master-of-the-elder-wand-updated-with-fantastic-b)

Comment: @Randal'Thor hypothetically this should not be closed if asked in the context of fantastic beasts maybe? UPDATE: [Would Nagini have become the master of the Elder Wand? (updated with fantastic beasts)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247069/would-nagini-have-become-the-master-of-the-elder-wand-updated-with-fantastic-b)

Answer (score 11):

### The Elder Wand never belonged to Snape.

> "Severus Snape was never the true master of the Elder Wand. He never defeated Dumbledore. [...] the Elder Wand recognised a new master before Dumbledore died, someone who never even laid a hand on it. The new master removed the wand from Dumbledore against his will, never realising exactly what he had done, or that the most powerful wand in history had given him its allegiance ... The true master of the Elder Wand was Draco Malfoy."
>
> <sub>-- Harry Potter, *HP and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 36: *The Flaw in the Plan*</sub>

The chain of Elder Wand masters went **Dumbledore -> Malfoy -> Harry**, not Dumbledore -> Snape -> Nagini -> Neville.

---

But if your question was more hypothetical (*assuming that Snape had been the master of the Elder Wand*, would Neville have become the master by killing Nagini?), the answer would still be **no**. Nagini was an animal and not a magic user, and could never have become the master of the Elder Wand. Her killing of Snape was on Voldemort's orders; Voldemort was the true killer. If Snape had become the master of the Elder Wand by killing Dumbledore, its mastery would then have passed to **Voldemort, not Nagini,** upon his death. This point is already covered in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54679/would-nagini-have-become-the-master-of-the-elder-wand) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106081/what-would-happen-to-the-elder-wand-if-a-living-horcrux-killed-its-current-wield?lq=1).

Comment: Perhaps quote the relevant part of the conversation between Harry and Olivander, when they were recovering at Shell Cottage?  The bit where Harry asks if you have to kill to claim a wand and Olivander says he doesn't think so?  That seems to be the OPs main point of confusion.

Comment: UPDATE: [Would Nagini have become the master of the Elder Wand? (updated with fantastic beasts)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247069/would-nagini-have-become-the-master-of-the-elder-wand-updated-with-fantastic-b)